# Magento 1.9 refresh shipping methods on saveBilling (OPC) from an observer

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, onepage-checkout

In the One Page Checkout the *saveBilling* step creates the Shipping Methods insert on the fly from the controller response (when `billing[use_for_shipping]` is selected), which you can retrieve from an observer like so:

```
/* @var $response Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http */
$response = $observer->getControllerAction()->getResponse();
$responseArray = Mage::helper('core')->jsonDecode($response->getBody());
```

However, the problem I've got is that the shipping value is a table rate based on the value of the shopping cart (e.g. *free shipping on orders over £25*) **and** there's a membership pricelist. This is all fine when someone logs into an account but it causes a problem with the guest checkout.

A field was added to the Billing section for customers to enter their membership number. When the *saveBilling* step is called the observer verifies the membership and recalculates the quote totals (`$quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals();`) ... this all works fine.

**However** it's possible that someone over the *free shipping* threshold drops below it when their pricelist is switched as some items are cheaper **but** the Shipping Methods insert has already been generated from the controller so the wrong shipping price is displayed.

I can work around it by removing prices from the template or manipulating the form - but those are both hacks. I'd like to be able to recreate the shipping methods response from the controller using the updated quote. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer**

If you need to update the values in a quote before the *saveBilling* event is despatched, to ensure the correct shipping method calculations, you need the **predespatch** event (which is fairly obvious really)... I was using the **postdespatch** event.

```
<controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_savebilling>
    <observers>
        ...
    </observers>
</controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_savebilling>
```

---

**Details**

Firstly I needed to move the membership validation in *config.xml* so that it's triggered before the controller action; that was a simple matter of changing it from the *postdespatch* even to *predespatch* and removing any code that utilised the `$observer->getControllerAction()` since that hasn't been despatched yet.

Now when the *saveBilling* controller is despatched it has the updated quote with the membership pricelist applied and the shipping prices are correctly calculated in the JSON response.

**However** the *saveBilling* controller seems to automatically set the `customer_group_id` to `0` when using the guest checkout so I had to add a method to the observer that's called *postdespatch* to check that the membership validation flag exists on the quote (part of the plugin) and, if so, set the customer group back again to members.